# How does one go about proving that something is a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

So I have this pretty theoretical problem for homework that says I need to show that this set of matrices is a vector space. It says that we have the set $M_{m,n}(\mathbb R)$, $m\times n$ matrices with entries from $\mathbb R$. And we also have $2$ arbitrary matrices $A=(a_{i,j})$ and $B=(b_{i,j})$, where $i$ is any row and $j$ is any column. Also, $A+B=(a_{i,j}+b_{i,j})$ and given any scalar $c$, $c\times A=(ca_{i,j})$. Now I need to show that with this information, the $10$ conditions hold that would define this as a vector space.. But how do I show it? By simply saying that since the $m\times n$ matrices have $\mathbb R$ entries and the $0$ entry is included, the zero vector $\vec 0$ must be in this set. I know that's only one part but is it that simple?

Comment: Yeah, you're going to end up using the fact that $\mathbb R$ is a field very heavily here.  It's as easy as you think it is.

Comment: The zero matrix *is* the zero vector in the vector space of $m \times n$ matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most introductory courses have exercises which amount to verify definitions, and exercise simple axiomatic manipulations.

This one is no different. You have a list of of axioms to verify, and you need to sit down and verify each one of them. Of course there are shortcuts, for example if you already know that finding an isomorphism to $\Bbb R^{m\cdot n}$ would prove this is a vector space, then by all means you should do that. But generally verifying the axioms is a laborious task which generally have an obvious way of doing.

Comment: I have a question for Asaf: just curious, why is being able to find an isomorphism to something proves that it is a vector space? And how can you find such an isomorphism?

Comment: @Jessica: If you have an addition and scalar multiplication defined, then showing that they behave the same as the addition and scalar multiplication of a known vector space would prove the needed properties hold.